# Coin flipping in a row

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

If we are flipping a coin and the probability of:
Heads: $\frac{1}{3}$
Tails: $\frac{2}{3}$
$W$: 2 results in a row: $T-T$ or $H-H$
If we are flipping until we have two in a row, what is $E[W]$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  In this case it is not difficult to describe all the paths to $TT$ or to $HH$...though I expect it is easier to compute $E_H$ and $E_T$ (where $E_X$ denotes the expected number of times it will take given that your prior toss was $X$).

Comment: I try to do like this: $E[W] = E[X| it's already flipped heads] + E[Y| it's already flipped tails]$, when $X$ is for tails and $Y$ is for heads. But how to continue now?

Comment: But that statement is not  true.  The first toss is either $T$ or $H$ with appropriate probabilities.  It follows that $E[W]=\frac 13\times (E_H+1)+\frac 23\times (E_T+1)$  where $E_T, E_H$ are as defined in my first comment.

Comment: $E_H=\frac{1}{3}$ and $E_T=\frac{2}{3}$ ?

Comment: What sense does that make?  How could you expect  it to take less than one toss to see a pair?

Comment: Try an easier problem.  What is the expected number of tosses it takes to see $HH$?

Comment: I'm confused now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $E_H(W)$ for the waiting time remaining  after the first  toss was H.
Then $E_H(W)=1+1/3+(2/3)E_T(W)$ and  $E_T(W)=1+2/3+(1/3)E_H(W)$, so $E_H(W)=22/7$  and $E_T(W)=19/7$. Finally $E(W)=1+E_H(W)/3+2E_T(W)/3=27/7.$

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the case where we want expected number of flips to get two heads.

Let $N$ be the number of flips to get two heads in a row.

Relating back to the above comments we get:

$E[N] = (1+E[N|\text{ previous toss was Heads}])P(\text{ Heads }) + (1+E[N|\text{ previous toss was Tails}])P(\text{ Tails })$

Notice here we are only looking for the expected number of tosses for $HH$. That that gives us that $E[N|\text{ previous toss was Tails}] = E[N]$ since if we got tails on the most recent toss then it is as if we are starting fresh plus the toss we 'wasted' trying to get the desired pattern.

As for $E[N|\text{ previous toss was Heads}]$ we will either get our desired second $H$ or we get $T$ and it reverts to the case where we need to get a first $H$ again. The plus one is not a wasted toss as in the case when the first toss was $T$ however we still made a toss to get $H$; hence, we add the 1 toss.

I will let you continue here and give the following hint:

$W = N + M$ where $N :=$ number of flips to get $HH$ and $M:=$ number of flips to get $TT$. So we can use linearity of expectation and break it down into two more understandable problems.